# Не применяется стиль width

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Сразу к делу.
Создаю структуру сайта, применяю вот такие стили:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;

}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.conteiner {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
    width: 64,28571428571429%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #333;
}
.site-bar {
    width: 21,42857142857143%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #1D2432;
}
.flexible-image {
    max-width: 100%;

}
```

В консоли разработчика выдаётся ошибка invalid property value на против width в content и site-bar

Comment: Заменить запятую на точку.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Заменить запятую на точку. – entithat

Замечательно!